# "Figure Page" Headers in LOF not showing up in all pages

Tags: tocloft

My List of Figures has 3 pages. I need the Figure and Page headers to appear in all pages, but for some reason they only appear in the first and second pages, not in the third one. I'm using [ASU Dissertation Template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/55124898eee6edb00c043cf2). The relevant code I believe is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\pagestyle{ASUlof}
\listoffigures

% List of Figures (LOF)
\copypagestyle{ASUlof}{ASU}
  \makeevenhead{ASUlof}{Figure}{}{Page}
  \makeoddhead{ASUlof}{Figure}{}{Page}
\copypagestyle{ASUlofFirst}{ASU}       
  \makeevenhead{ASUlofFirst}           
{}
{\printchaptertitle{\listfigurename}}
{} 
  \makeoddhead{ASUlofFirst}
{}
{\printchaptertitle{\listfigurename}}
{}  
\renewcommand{\lofheadstart}{}         
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}[1]{}     
\renewcommand{\afterloftitle}{         
  \thispagestyle{ASUlofFirst}          
  Figure\hfill Page\par}                

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that illustrates your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and convert your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your document does not compile. There is no `\begin{document}`, and you have to load some packages before your commands will work.